# From kafka to hdfs through spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs, spark-streaming

Maybe somebody has used this in some project: I write to Cassandra from Spark, and in Spark I use `kafkaUtils.createDirectStream`. Through the Spark-Cassandra connector we can use the `Dstream.saveToCassandra` method. But for saving/appending to hdfs I use:

```
stream.map(_.value).foreachRDD(rdd => {
  val conf = new Configuration()
  conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000/")
  val fs = FileSystem.get(conf)
  fs.append(new Path("textfile.txt"))
    .write(rdd.collect().mkString.getBytes())
  fs.close()
})
```

But I don't think it is the best way to do this. It may be better to use something like:

```
val prepStr = {
  val str = new StringBuilder
  if (!rdd.isEmpty()) {
    str.append(rdd.collect().mkString)
  }
  str
}
```

And finally:

```
fs.append(path).write(prepStr.mkString.getBytes())
```

Or maybe somebody used another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your stream is of type `DStream[String]` you could make use of the append function offered by the dataframe writer:

```
dstream.foreachRDD{rdd => 
    import sparkSession.implicits._
    val df = rdd.toDF()
    df.write.mode("append").text("/hdfs/path/to/file")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i will try to test this in such way

Comment: No, it writes as files in path, but not appending to existing file

Comment: It appends to the logical file which you can read back. But indeed it will be composed of many internal partitions.

Comment: Thanks, i will think, what is better for me

Comment: @IvanAlex  Are you writing to a local file or a hdfs (clustered)  file?

Comment: as i wrote in begining, i write to hdfs file, i want to append to file in some period,as archive, for example for a day, so i will have big files in hdfs. I think this is better for hdfs, than i use your way. May be you have another opinion?